# F2063 Could not compile used unit 'QuickPDF0724.pas'' error in Delphi XE4

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe4

I have included `QuickPDF0724` unit in uses in one of my pas file. I have give the path of this unit in Tools --> Options. But I am getting the error: "`F2063 Could not compile used unit 'QuickPDF0724.pas'`"

In the path mentioned of that unit, only dcu file is there, no pas file.

Same code is working fine in Delphi 7 but not in Delphi XE4. What could be the reason?

Comment: What about your previous questions? Are they finished yet?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I have commented and accepted your answer.

Comment: And what about this one too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19806591/undeclared-identifier-checkstates-in-delphi-xe4-while-dealing-with-tcxcheckgroup

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I have given answer to that question.

Comment: It looks to me as though Jan's answer is the correct one. I still feel that you should fix that question to include the different DevEx versions since that's actually the issue. It's important to wrap these questions up. I guess you've got a solution to your problem, but we care about the questions. There's a subtle difference between the problem that you have to solve, and the questions that you ask and we try to answer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - cxCheckGroup1.CheckStates didn't work. cxCheckGroup1.ACheckStates worked. I will include extra information in my answer. Now please answer this question. I am stuck here. :)

Comment: I think that Jan just slipped up in his answer. When he said `CheckStates` in the final paragraph he surely meant `States`. Look at the code higher up the answer. That looks like the right answer to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In the path mentioned of that unit, only dcu file is there, no pas file.

DCUs are Delphi version dependent.

So your DCU made in Delphi 7 cannot be read by Delphi XE4 and by any other Delphi version but Delphi 7 (with the same set of updates installed - those updates may change Delphi RTL and make dependencies in those DCUs fail).

That means you either need to take `QuickPDF0724.pas` and compile it with your version of Delphi XE4, or you need to find someone who would do it for you and then send you the resulting DCU they made (wither possible - made exactly for the same Build of Delphi XE4 (Build number is changed by installing update packs) as you have).

Comment: Since when does the build number matter? It hasn't always been important. Usually, the DCU format only changes on major releases, except for Delphi 2007, which could read Delphi 2006 DCUs.

Comment: @Arioch - Unfortunately since this is a third party library, we don't have the pas file for it

Comment: @nkp then ask library vendor to give it to you, just like he gave you D7 DCU

Comment: @RobKennedy format itself may stay, but dependencies on RTL, etc? Okay, i'd try to rephrase it in more conservative manner.

Comment: @Arioch'The - I got QuickPDF0724 dcu compiled under Delphi XE. But using that in Delphi XE4, I am getting same error. Should I have to strictly use QuickPDF0724 dcu compiled under Delphi XE4 to get rid of this error?

Comment: yes. Ken White there above told the ONLY example when one compiler produced DCUs and DCPs binary-compatible with another compiler. Actually those DCUs and DCPs are just compiler cache, and as every cache it is very expendable and very narrow-aimed. You really have to communicate with library vendor.

Answer (score 0):

My Delphi 7 application was using `QuickPDF0724` and same I was trying in Delphi XE4. QuickPDF0724 has version number 7.24. This was not compatible with Delphi XE4.

So, I downloaded latest version of QuickPDF i,e `DebenuPDFLibrary1011` having version number 10.11 which is compatible with Delphi XE4.

I did few changes in the code like:

1. Changed unit name in uses from `QuickPDF0724` to `DebenuPDFLibrary1011`.
2. Changed declaration in the code like `objQuickPDF : TDebenuPDFLibrary1011` from `objQuickPDF : TQuickPDF0724`
3. Changed constructor: `objQuickPDF := TDebenuPDFLibrary1011.Create` instead of `objQuickPDF := TQuickPDF0724.Create`

Rest was fine...